# Set RGB white to transparent?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mask, imshow

I have an image I load into python using `matplotlib.pyplot.imread` which ends up as an `numpy` array containing an array of rgb values.  Here is a dummy snippet with all but two pixel white:

```
>>> test
array([[[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[  1, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255,   6, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
```

I want to create a mask out all the white pixels.  I think I could do something similar to

```
>>> mask = (test != [255, 255, 255])
```

which would give:

```
array([[[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True]]], dtype=bool)
```

How do I do this?

Alternatively, I would think there is an input parameter for [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) which does this but the documentation is not clear how.  It seems `alpha` would change the entire image and `vmax` accepts a scaler which does not seem compatible with RGB colors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to construct a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) and then `imshow` it:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.array([[[255, 255, 255],
               [255, 255, 255]],
              [[  1, 255, 255],
               [255, 255, 255]],
              [[255, 255, 255],
               [255,   6, 255]]], dtype=np.uint8)

mask = np.all(x == 255, axis=2, keepdims=True)

# broadcast the mask against the array to make the dimensions the same
x, mask = np.broadcast_arrays(x, mask)

# construct a masked array
mx = np.ma.masked_array(x, mask)

plt.imshow(mx)
```

Masked values will be rendered transparent.

Another option would be to convert your RGB array to an RGBA array, with the alpha channel set to zero wherever the red, green and blue channels are all equal to 255.

```
alpha = ~np.all(x == 255, axis=2) * 255
rgba = np.dstack((x, alpha)).astype(np.uint8)

plt.imshow(rgba)
```

Note that I had to cast `rgba` back to uint8 after the concatenation, since `imshow` expects RGBA arrays to either be uint8 or float.

Comment: Note that Matplotlib's `imread` scales rgba values to be floating point values between 0 and 1.  Coming back to this, I wanted to do this again with an image that was encoded in rgba, just with all the alpha values set to 1.0.  Inspired by the last code block, I ended up using `alpha = np.all(rgba[:, :, :3] == 1, axis=2)` and `rgba[alpha, 3] = 0.0` which worked out.

Comment: I like the adding alpha channel idea!

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired mask output you can do something like this -

```
wpix = np.array([255,255,255])        
out = np.tile(np.atleast_3d(np.any(test != wpix,axis=2)),(1,1,test.shape[2]))
```

Alternatively, since a white pixel is all `255's`, you can do this too -

```
out = np.tile(np.atleast_3d(np.any(test != 255,axis=2)),(1,1,test.shape[2]))
```

Comment: This generates the mask array I wanted but when I try to plot the images using `ax.imshow(np.ma.masked_where(out, test))` it still shows white.

Comment: @stvn66 Yeah after doing some research, I am inclining towards this conclusion that this transparency option with imshow isn't compatible with RGB images, if not straight-forward with masking using `np.ma.masked_where`.

Answer (score -2):

I think, the way to go would be to create a RGBA array and to input it to imgshow.

You want to obtain

```
mask = array([[[False],[False]],[[True],[False]],[[False],[True]]]]
```

Then:

```
alphaChannel = 255*mask;
img = np.concatenate((test,alphaChannel), axis=2);
plt.imshow(img);
```

Sorry for not testing it and not giving the way to compute mask.

[Note: For me, matplotlib always works with float between 0 and 1 instead of integer, but I guess both are valid]